# Defined variable in bash loop cannot be compared correctly

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, compare

Creat 2 files at first:

```
cat <<'EOF'> test
f u u 1624268497
f3 u2 u2 1624268498
EOF


cat <<'EOF'> test_new
f u4 u5 16242684973
f4 u2 u2 1624268498
f3 u2 u2 1624268498
EOF
```

I want to loop files to list the unique element of `test_new`,script as below:

```
##!/bin/bash
added=()
while read F_NEW O_NEW G_NEW P_NEW; do
    exist=0
    while read F O G P; do
    #exist in both old & new
    if [[ $F_NEW == $F ]]; then
        exist=1
        break
    fi
    #   echo "tester: $F"
    done < test
    if [ $exist == 0 ]; then
    echo $F_NEW
        added+=($F_NEW)
    fi

done < test_new

printf '%s\n' "${added[*]}"
```

Expect result is:

```
f4
```

but I got:

```
f4 f3
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: `but I got:` I run your code as is and I got only `f4` printed twice. [Can't reproduce.](https://replit.com/@kamilcukrowski/SpringgreenPlasticInterfacestandard#main.sh).

Comment: I can reproduce the output when I remove the `echo $_NEW` and add a non-printable character (e.g. `$'\x01'`) before the `f3` in `test_new`.

Comment: I only get f4 displayed twice. If you remove **echo $F_NEW** I get the expected output f4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk is a good candidate for a problem such as this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { arr[$1]=1;next } arr[$1] != "1" { print $1 }' test test_new
```

Process the test file first (NR==FNR) Create an array called arr keyed by the first space delimited field. Then when processing the test_new file, if there isn't an entry in arr for the first field, print the first field.

Comment: If loop is long,I tried `awk 'NR==FNR { arr[$1]=1;next } arr[$1] != "1" { added+= $1 }' test test_new`
`printf '%s\n' "${added[@]}"` but there's no output.what's the problem?

Comment: try readarray -t added <<< "$(awk 'NR==FNR { arr[$1]=1;next } arr[$1] != "1" { added+= $1 }' test test_new)";printf '%s\n' "${added[@]}"